# BaseX XQuery command to get XML file name

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex, xquery-sql

I have multiple XML files in a BaseX database:

[image]

Is there a XQuery or BaseX function to get the file name? In the example above i wanted an other query that returns DB03.xml as output.

Comment: In the context of XML databases, usually the `doc` and `collection` functions, besides db specific modules, help, see whether http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Databases#XML_Documents gives you the options you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try URIs functions ?
http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0023.html#c0056

For example :

```
base-uri(//ITEM[@name="A"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases where `base-uri(//ITEM[@name="A"])` would throw error *[XQST0046] URI  'path/to/file' is invalid* better use `db:path(//ITEM[@name="A"])` with no such error, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702662.